# NineOldAndroids for MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to use NineOldAndroids to enable backwards compatibility with pre-3.x devices, but I am encountering the following build error:

> .../NineOldAndroids/obj/Debug/generated/src/Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.AnimatorSet.cs(83,83):
>   Error CS0508:
>   `Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.AnimatorSet.SetDuration(long)': return
>   type must be`Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.Animator' to match
>   overridden member
>   `Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.Animator.SetDuration(long)' (CS0508)
>   (NineOldAndroids)

but the signature in generated code looks like this:

```
public override global::Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.AnimatorSet SetDuration (long p0)
```

and the class signature of AnimatorSet looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class AnimatorSet : global::Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.Animator {
```

The problem is, since AnimatorSet is inherited from Animator, I'm not sure why it should be a problem.

Are there any examples of binding NineOldAndroids for MonoDroid that you're aware of or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These error messages are because C# doesn't support [Covariant Return Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) while Java ≥1.5 does.

Add these lines to `Transforms/Metadata.xml`:

```
<attr path="/api/package/class[@name='AnimatorSet']/method[@name='setDuration']" name="managedReturn">Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.Animator</attr>
<attr path="/api/package/class[@name='ValueAnimator']/method[@name='setDuration']" name="managedReturn">Com.Nineoldandroids.Animation.Animator</attr>
```